# Is there any way to know that which categorical value has been given what label?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, label-encoding

I am working with this data containing a categorical column which has "Good","Medium","Bad", now I wish to know which number has been assigned to which category, i.e. is medium assigned 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you use sklearn `le.classes_` give the names of the classes enumerating them :

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

mylist = ['r', 'z', 'd', 'd', 'r', 'a']

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(mylist)

>>> array([2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0])

le.classes_

>>> array(['a', 'd', 'r', 'z'], dtype='<U1')
```

You can check using `inverse_transform` :

```py
list(le.inverse_transform([i for i in range(len(le.classes_))]))

>>> ['a', 'd', 'r', 'z']
```